# Let $A$ be an nxn matrix such that the first $3$ rows of $A$ are linearly independent and the first $5$ columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix such that the first $3$ rows of $A$ are linearly independent and the first $5$ columns of $A$ are linearly independent. Which of the following statements are true?

1. $A$ has at least $5$ linearly independent rows
2. $3\leq rankA \leq 5 $
3. $rank A \geq 5. $
4. $rank(A^2)\geq 5. $

Using the concept that row rank(A)=column rank(A) I could conclude that option 1 and option 3 are correct. Choose $A=I_n, n>6.$ We can conclude that option 2 is incorrect. I couldn't able to find a counter example for option 4. How to disprove option 4? Please help me.

Comment: Think of a nilpotent matrix

Comment: okay. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n=10$. Then because the matrix is square, $$\mathrm{rank}~ A^2 \geq 2~\mathrm{rank}~A - (\text{# of columns})$$
Then $$\mathrm{rank}~A^2 ≥ 2(5)-10 = 0$$
So option 4 is wrong.